# "flag a moderator" in chat

Tags: feature-request

This is a proposal for improvement of prompts.  It is based on my own humble experience.  Yesterday I clicked "flag a moderator" and misinterpreted the prompt about the importance of the issue.

When one clicks on the arrow to the left of a comment in chat, one of the options is 
 "flag a moderator"  Is there any way to change that to **"flag ANY AVAILABLE MODERATOR from the STACK EXCHANGE!"** since that is what results.

Likewise, I misinterpreted the prompt about the importance of the issue.  Is it possible to make this prompt even more clear, like, **"Are you SURE your issue warrants the IMMEDIATE attention of ALL THE MODERATORS from the ENTIRE STACK EXCHANGE (not just from this forum)** that is what this action will do."

It is likely not a problem for computer savvy people who are used to the way forums work.  But, your unsuspecting computer illiterate folk will may well provide you with an occasional "drill" if left as is.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting this.  I was thinking about this same issue last night and was wondering if something could be done. We can elevate this issue after we've had a chance to discuss it together here.

Comment: It's really helpful to bring this to our attention, and sorry you had the stress of having all those grumpy mods from other sites come in our chat room and moan at you ;)

Comment: @Jack Douglas, LOL,They handled it well, all of them.  I was puzzled when suddenly someone from the Muslim forum appeared (thought maybe somehow he caught wind of our discussion of aramaic-LOL).  I was beside myself when an unfamiliar name informed me that I had flagged ALL the moderators from the stack exchange.  I was encouraged when Jon said it was OK.  I was directed to and wealth of information by one of the mods (which by the way looked strangely familiar, so I must have forgotten the information, which I doubt I'll do again!  It was a shocking learning experience.  But they were kind.